# Programmes won't run on Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, ubuntu

Having installed Eclipse and CB, I encountered several projects that do not start properly. I assumed that it was because of the OS I used, that is why I switched to Ubuntu. However, some programmes I had tried to run still would not work correctly. For instance, this code from  clc-wiki outputs nothing upon pushing Enter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 40 /* maximum input line size */

int getlines(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */
int main()
{
int c;
int len;    /* current line length */
int max;    /* maximum length seen so far */
char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

max = 0;

while ((len = getlines(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
    if (line[len-1] != '\n')
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            ++len;

    if (len > max) {
        max = len;
        copy(longest, line);
    }
}

if (max > 0) {    /* there was a line */
    printf("Longest line with %d characters:\n", max);
    printf("%s ...\n", longest);
}

return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line s, return length */
int getlines(char s[], int lim)
{
int c, i;

for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    s[i] = c;
if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
}
s[i] = '\0';

return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
int i;

i = 0;
while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;
}
```

The similar problem is faced, if we run it in XP. Nevertheless, everything is perfect, if we compile the very same code in [ideone](https://ideone.com/VMRqk2).

gcc and g++ are installed, as well as mingw for Windows.

Could you please tell me what the problem can be all about?

Comment: Can you understand this code? Do you know what is its expected input and output? And do you know how to run it properly?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but is there any particular reason you're writing your own `copy` method and not using `string.h`'s `strcpy` or `strncpy`?

Comment: Dear Lee Duhem,

Unfortunately, I do not understand the code completely, i.e I am not able to write it all by myself. 

I consider the input to be everything that I type in. 

If I push the Run button after building the project (eg in CB), do I run it properly?

Comment: Dear Powerlord, I think it is an exercise for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this code outputs nothing upon pushing Enter

That is the correct behavior of your code. It is designed to print nothing upon pushing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That code, in particular, requires an end-of-file indication. If your program reads from a file (as is the case on ideone), the end-of-file indication happens more-or-less automatically. If your program reads from the computer keyboard (as when you run it interactively), then you must provide an end-of-file indication.

To exercise the code you provided:

On Linux, from the keyboard, enter several lines of varying lengths, each followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then enter <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> on a line by itself.

On Windows, from the keyboard, enter several lines of varying lengths, each followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then enter enter <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> on a line by itself.

Comment: Dear Rob,

Thank you very much for your time.

It works.

I am really sorry for my bluntness.

Comment: @Delly - There are no apologies required. I am glad that I am able to help. If my answer, or any other answer, satisfied your question, please "accept" it by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer.